# How to bind a property to text block/ textbox?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Here is my DemoModel.cs class

```
    public int Age  {get; set;}
```

DemoViewModel.cs

```
DemoViewModel() 
{
    DemoModel dm = new DemoModel();
    dm.Age = 22;
}
```

My View

```
  <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Age,Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
```

when i run the above program i didnt get anything bind to my textblock..Kindly post your valuable suggestions 
TIA

Comment: Are you setting the DataContext of your view with the object of DemoViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work. 
You need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event to notify the view that your property has changed.
Now bind the `Age` property to `TextBlock` and it should work fine.

```
public class DemoViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int age;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set
        {
           if (value != age)
           {
              age = value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged("Age");
           }     
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Also ensure that your views `DataContext` is set to the `DemoViewModel`.

Comment: i tired the above but the result is same.. yes i have set the `DataContext` to `DemoViewModel`...

`public partial class DemoView : UserControl
    {

        private DemoViewModel _viewModel;
        public DemoViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return _viewModel; }
            set { _viewModel = value; }
        }
        public DemoView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = new Demo.ViewModel.DemoViewModel();
                this.DataContext = ViewModel;
        }
    } `

Comment: Ensure that your view model class is public `public class DemoViewModel`. It is working fine at my end.

Comment: yes already it is set to public.. am i need to change anything in my mainwindow.. 
`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo.ViewModel"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Demo.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DemoViewModel}">
            <views:DemoView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <views:DemoView x:Name="DemoView" />

    </Grid>`

Comment: No this is just more than enough. 
You’re setting the DataContext properly and it is supposed to work. I don’t find any issues in your code.
Just set some test value to `Age` in `Constructor` and put break point and check whether the value is getting set.

Answer (score 0):

In view

specify the DataContext in View

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo.ViewModel" 
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Demo.View"
xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Demo.ViewModel"
mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow"
Height="350" Width="525"> 
<window.DataContext>
 <viewModel:DemoViewModel/>
</window.DataContext>
<grid>
<TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Age,Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
</grid>
```

In ViewModel

```
public class DemoViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 private int age;

 public int Age
{
get { return age; }
set
{
   if (value != age)
   {
      age = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("Age");
   }     
}
}

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
if (PropertyChanged != null)
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
}
}
}
```

In Model

```
public int Age  {get; set;}
```

Normally this should solve your problem. if you are using then try to avoid writing code behind the view. in my example sets the datacontext in xaml itself